# What is the proper term for a bug fix with respect to Software Development

Tags: word-requests

In English, when dealing with Software Development we sometimes refer to the word "fix" in order to describe some code change which makes an attempt to fix a bug, or problem in the code. For example:

> I'll try to send you a bug fix which addresses this issue by the end
>   of the day.

I'm a little unsure about what the best way to express this concept of "fix" in Japanese. My guess is 修正, but I haven't seen this used in this fashion often, if ever. My guess at a translation would be:

> 今日中にこのバグに対応する修正を送ります。

Would this be the most natural way to describe this? If there is any other terms please let me know.

EDIT: It's very interesting to note that this post received over 1000 views in less than a day. This gives further proof to my theory that there is a strong correlation with English-speaking Software Developers and interest in learning Japanese (:

Comment: Candidates might be "バグ対応”？ "バグ除去｛じょきょ｝”？

Comment: 閲覧数が1000 を超えているのは、[Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?page=2) のリストに載っているからだと思います。今、[画面右にこう見えています。](https://scontent.fitm1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s480x480/13423927_933382763436274_2379154255001927012_n.jpg?oh=7e8401d747598fd12cd711e0aa8ac99c&oe=57D2581D)

Comment: なるほど！そういう理由なんですね。

Comment: +1 as I asked a same kind of topic so that I hope even this is technical, I personally them to be allowed here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use バグ修正{しゅうせい} to refer to a bug fix, and a release which specifically fixes bugs is a バグ修正{しゅうせい}リリース. There's also 脆弱性{ぜいじゃくせい} which refers to a vulnerability, which would also be addressed with a 修正{しゅうせい}. User naruto points out in the comments that バグフィックス is also common and acceptable.

edit: I've been working as a developer in Japan for a while now, and looking back on this I think that 不具合{ふぐあい} is likely the most appropriate, as pointed out in the comments by user Tommy. バグ is perfectly fine, and indeed in my workplace both are used, but 不具合 is the more 'correct' term. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: +1 but バグフィックス is also very common among developers.

Comment: I actually work as a developer and I can confirm that  when referring to bugs (バグ)  修正 is very common as well as  フィックス as @naruto said.
Being a person who terribly dislikes katakana though, I wanted to add for reference that actually there is also a (in my opinion, "more Japanese") word for "bug" that is 不具合{ふぐあい}. I almost never heard it in spoken language but saw it a few times in internal documents.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This answer was based mostly around browsing software-related subreddits and message boards in Japanese and I only ever really see 修正.

Comment: Could it also be combined as 不具合修正?

Comment: @Tek absolutely!